# Set background color of NSView and NSImageView in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, background-color

I have a some NSViews % NSImageView that I made in IB, how can I set up a background color for each when the app awakesFromNib?

After google and search here, i found that can be done by creating Custom class of NSView or NSImageView and set color in their drawRect method.

Is their any other way by which i can set background color, and no need to create extra class for View/ImageView.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way. You need to subclass view to set background color.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Their are two way to set background color of NSView/NSImageView, which i found.

**First:** By Subclassing of `NSView/NSImageView`

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)aRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}
```

**Second:**

> Don't want to make subclass, as you mentioned in your question.
>   Then

```
[_backgroundView setWantsLayer:YES];
[_backgroundView.layer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor redColor] CGColor]]];
```

Here `_backgroundView` is the IBOutlet/object of `NSView/NSImageView`. You just need to access layer of `NSView/NSImageView` for giving him backgroundcolor without subclassing them.

Comment: Can the "Second" (or something similar) be done w/o CGColor? F.e. on system versions, which didn't have CGColor available?

Comment: @silverdr On which version you are working ? Also you are using Objective-C or Swift ?

Comment: I target 10.6+ (the lowest allowed by Mother Apple these days) using Obj-C.

Answer (score 12):

you cannot draw something custom without subclassing NSView however you can change background colour of layer.

```
[yourView setWantsLayer: YES];
[yourView.layer setBackgroundColor: [NSColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a background color to any NSView descendant via Interface Builder by implementing a category extension like this:

```
@implementation NSView (backgroundColor)

- (void)setBgColor:(NSColor *)color {
    //
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    self.layer = [CALayer layer];
    [self.layer setBackgroundColor:[color CGColor]];
}

@end
```

and provide a value for it in the User Defined Runtime Attributes panel in IB:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you can change the `NSImageView` background color like this:

```
self.myBackgroundView.wantsLayer = true
self.myBackgroundView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

if you want an image as background you can use the following:

```
self.myBackgroundView.wantsLayer = true
let image : NSImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageResourceName")
self.myBackgroundView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.init(patternImage: image).cgColor
```